# Count volume of dates and label

Tags: r

Having an input like this:

```
data.frame(class = c("a","b","a","a"), date = c(2010,2009,2010,2009))
```

How is it possible to have an output which counts how many time a value exist in class column over specific years (date column) and have its volume. Example of expected output

> ```
> class date volume
> a      2009  1
> b      2009  1
> a      2010  2
> b      2010  0
> ```

Comment: dplyr::count(df, class, date) would work in your case.

Comment: try `as.data.frame(table(df))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <-data.frame(class = c("a","b","a","a"), date = c(2010,2009,2010,2009))
```

Solution using base R:

```
  table(df$class, df$date)
```

Returns:

```
  2009 2010
a    1    2
b    1    0
```

Solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.factor(date)) %>% 
  group_by(class, date, .drop=FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(N = n())
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   class [2]
  class date      N
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 a     2009      1
2 a     2010      2
3 b     2009      1
4 b     2010      0
```

With `dplyr` we have to make sure both grouping variables are factors and that we use the parameter `.drop=FALSE`. This way empty groups are **not** droped.

Answer (score 1):

Use the reshape2 library.  If you don't care about the shape of the output you can just stop at `dcast` below.  If you want output like you've specified, you have to run `melt` again to get it into the right format:

```
library(reshape2)
x <- data.frame(class = c("a","b","a","a"), date = c(2010,2009,2010,2009))
y <- dcast(x, class~date, fun.aggregate = length)
melt(y, id.vars='class', variable.name='volume')
```